5.72.2 has broken something in CiviCRM and now front end functions don't function
After installing 5.72.2 we seem to have lost the ability to access Civi functions from the front end. Search is broken , contributions is broken (links to PayPal and Stripe) just don't get anywhere.
Where do I need to be looking to try and work out why this has happened?
Running Joomla 4.4.4 , PHP 8.1.24 and CiviCRM 5.72.2
Anyone out there with in-depth knowledge of CiviCRM under Joomla feel free to reach out, I have authority to spend some money for a full audit of the site

I'm also getting this appear as well at times:
Error We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.

Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.Error type: Could not find a valid session key.

is it possible that you have settings that include both http and https or www and no www?

re professional help request, there is no way to 'reach out' to you via SE, well, only for administrators who can access your email - maybe put a request in the https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/joomla or you could DM me via that forum. we don't do a lot of joomla but do provide support to one org who uses it and have helped them out of difficulties

It helps to have more information:
Search is broken - Which search. How is it broken?
contributions is broken - What do you mean? Do you mean making a contribution via a CiviCRM donation page used to work and now doesn't? At what point does it break?
(links to PayPal and Stripe) just don't get anywhere. -> Are you using extensions to provide this functionality? If so which extensions? Have you upgraded them to the latest version?

Hi Luke, in terms of extensions everything is up to date. By "search being broken" what I mean is that a profile form that has been exposed to the front end that allows member to search will take inputs (e.g. last name) , appears to go away and do something but returns no results at all. Same form accessed from the backend works (I'm a Super User as well).
Paypal and Stripe, we have an entry form to allow people to enter their details and then select payment method. Then they are asked to "review" what they have entered, press that and it just returns the entry form. Again backend works

This now appears at times as well , I have set myself up a test environment that is a mirror of live so if I break it anymore than it is broken it doesn't matter however I am now getting this message popping up:
Error type: Could not find a valid session key.

And have you found any errors in your CiviCRM ConfigAndLog , CMS logs (if any) or php logs that correspond to the problems?

Nothing obvious Luke , still working my way through them step by step

I will change my headline , there is something in 5.72.0 that has caused the issue. I reverted my test site back to 5.70.0 and all the functions that I expect to work correctly do indeed work correctly.
I then installed 5.70.1 , 5.70.2 , 5.71.1 , 5.71.2 and all was well. Installed 5.72.0 and , bang, contributions stopped working and the search screen just went round back to where it started with no results diplayed at all.
So my "fix" at the moment is to revert my live site back to 5.71.2 and the try and work out what in 5.72.0 broke things
